# Scrollview does not respond to calling animateTo()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a login page with a form on it. When a text field is tapped, I have used a focus node to trigger the scroll view to scroll down so that the keyboard doesn't cover the large "Log In" button.

I set up my focus node like this:

```
final FocusNode passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
final FocusNode emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

void setUpFocusNodeListeners() {
    passwordFocusNode.addListener(() {
      scrollToBottom();
    });

    emailFocusNode.addListener(() {
      scrollToBottom();
    });
}

 void scrollToBottom() {
    print("Should have animated to the bottom");
    scrollController.animateTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }
```

**When I tap into one the top text fields, even though "Should have animated to the bottom" is printed, the scrollview doesn't shift and the keyboard covers the log in button.** I don't want the keyboard to cover the log in button, I would rather the whole UI shift up when the keyboard is opened. This is strange, as `scrollToBottom()` is in fact being triggered, but it just looks like `animateTo()` isn't doing anything.

The whole page is wrapped in a `SingleChildScrollView` and I made sure to set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to true. Where could I be going wrong here? Full page code:

```
return ViewModelBuilder.reactive(
        viewModelBuilder: () => LoginViewModel(),
        onViewModelReady: (model) => model.setUpFocusNodeListeners(),
        builder: (context, model, _) {
          return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: model.scrollController,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 70.w,
                      child: Center(
                          child: Image.asset(
                        ImageAssets.loginLogo,
                      )),
                    ),
                    Form(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: AppPadding.registrationSidePadding
                                .scale(context)),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical:
                                          AppPadding.loginPageTextFieldPadding),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                    style: Fonts.inputTextStyle.scale(context),
                                    focusNode: model.emailFocusNode,
                                    onTapOutside: (e) {
                                      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!
                                          .unfocus();
                                      model.checkAllFieldsValid();
                                    },
                                    onChanged: (value) =>
                                        model.checkAllFieldsValid(),
                                    onEditingComplete: () =>
                                        model.onEditingCompleteEmail(),
                                    controller:
                                        model.emailOrMobileNumberController,
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: "Email"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ErrorText(text: model.emailErrorMessage),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top:
                                          AppPadding.loginPageTextFieldPadding),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    style: Fonts.inputTextStyle.scale(context),
                                    onTapOutside: (e) => FocusManager
                                        .instance.primaryFocus!
                                        .unfocus(),
                                    obscureText: !model.passwordVisible,
                                    focusNode: model.passwordFocusNode,
                                    onChanged: (value) =>
                                        model.checkAllFieldsValid(),
                                    onEditingComplete: () =>
                                        model.onEditingCompletePassword(),
                                    controller: model.passwordController,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                          onPressed:
                                              model.togglePasswordVisible,
                                          icon: Icon(
                                              model.passwordVisible
                                                  ? Icons.visibility_off
                                                  : Icons.visibility,
                                              color: Colors.grey),
                                        ),
                                        hintText: "Password"),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ErrorText(text: model.passwordErrorMessage)
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 13.h, // works?
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () => AppServices
                                          .navigationService
                                          .navigateTo(Routes.forgotPassword),
                                      child: const Text("Forgot Password?")),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: AppNums.minimumElevatedButtonHeight
                                        .scale(context),
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      style: !model.allFieldsValid! ||
                                              model.isBusy
                                          ? Theme.of(context)
                                              .elevatedButtonTheme
                                              .style!
                                              .copyWith(
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                                          AppColors
                                                              .disabledPink))
                                          : Theme.of(context)
                                              .elevatedButtonTheme
                                              .style,
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          !model.allFieldsValid! || model.isBusy
                                              ? {}
                                              : model.login(),
                                      child: !model.isBusy
                                          ? const Text("Log In")
                                          : const CircularProgressIndicator
                                              .adaptive(
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Need to Create an Account?",
                    style: Fonts.notoSansSerif,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => AppServices.navigationService
                          .replaceWith(Routes.register),
                      child: const Text("Sign Up"))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

Comment: When you open the keyboard, the widget rebuilds, and that may interfere with the scrolling animation.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan i figured as much, but what do you think I could do to get the desired behavior? In the past I have tried checking if `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` are greater than 0 and then adding a sizedbox underneath to push everything up, but it doesn't appear to be reliable at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. The behavior I was trying to go for was simply just moving the Login button above the keyboard, and the problem was that I had the Image rendered above the form to be 70.w - a fixed height for the SizedBox. So, when the keyboard opened up, it didn't move.

I solved this problem by removing all of the manual `scrollToBottom()` code and just wrapped both the `Image` and the `Form` in an `Expanded` so they will move around when the keyboard is opened.